# converting C code to Python by hand

Tags: python, c

Im am trying to covert the following C code to Python. I have no experience in C but a little in Python.

```
main( int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char a[] = "ds dsf ds sd dsfas"; 
    unsigned char c; 
    int d, j; 

    for(d = 0; d < 26; d++) 
    { 
        printf("d = %d: ", d); 
        for (j = 0; j < 21; j++ ) 
        { 
            if( a[j] == ' ') 
            c = ' '; 
            else 
            { 
                c = a[j] + d; 
                if (c > 'z') 
                c = c - 26; 
            }    
            printf("%c", c); 
    } 
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

I have managed to up to this point: Where I get an  list index out of range exception, any suggestions?

```
d=0
a=["ds dsf ds sd dsfas"]
while (d <26):

    print("d = ",d)
    d=d+1

    j=0
    while(j<21):

        if a[j]=='':
            c =''
        else:
            c = answer[j]+str(d)
            if c>'z':
                c=c-26
        j=j+1
        print("%c",c)
```

Comment: Hint: Reason what the C program is trying to do and then code it in Python. Don't translate literally.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com/ may be more appropriate.

Comment: There are also a lot of answers here on SO on how to brute force Caesar's cyphers.

Comment: Your C doesn't even compile, and even if it did, I see at least one logic error (you use indexes up to 21 on a string on length 18. Why no `strlen`?)

Comment: Also, the character arithmetic in the C isn't doing what you think it is. Although it works, it's not really alphabet arithmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this does what your C code is trying to achieve:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

import string

a = 'ds dsf ds sd dsfas' #input
for d in range (26): #the 26 possible Caesar's cypher keys
    shift = string.ascii_lowercase [d:] + string.ascii_lowercase [:d] #rotate the lower ase ascii with offset d
    tt = string.maketrans (string.ascii_lowercase, shift) #convenience function to create a transformation, mapping each character to its encoded counterpart
    print 'd = {}:'.format (d) #print out the key
    print a.translate (tt) #translate the plain text and print it
```

Comment: Thanks for this, could you possibly add comments to explain what each line does?

Comment: why do you use ascii numbers?

Comment: @Pro-grammer In your C code, `a[j]` and `'z'` are also "ascii numbers".

Answer (score 0):

the loop executes till j becomes 21.But I dont think you have that many elements in the `a` list. Thats why you get the error. I think `len(a)` is 18. So changing the loop as:

```
while j<len(a):
    #code
```

or

```
while j<18:
    #code
```

Will clear the error

Answer (score -1):

See this, It's been explained with comments:

```
d=0
a=["ds dsf ds sd dsfas"]

# this will print 1 as a is a list object 
# and it's length is 1 and a[0] is "ds dsf ds sd dsfas"
print len(a) 

# and your rest of program is like this
while (d <26):
    print("d = ",d)
    d=d+1

    #j=0
    # while(j<21): it's wrong as list length is 1
    # so it will give list index out of bound error
    # in c array does not check for whether array's index is within
    # range or not so it will not give out of bound error
    for charValue in a: 
        if charValue is '':
            c =''
        else:
            c = charValue +str(d) # here you did not initialized answer[i]
            if c>'z':
                c=c-26
        #j=j+1
        print("%c",c)
```

Comment: This doesnt give the right output as the c program, see this:http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130422003626AAUFGHn

Comment: Because in C program you are using values beyond the range of char array char a[] = "ds dsf ds sd dsfas", it's length is 18 so the last index is 17, Hence a[18],a[19], a[20] will give some garbage value. that's why you are not getting the same result in both